# Can I loop through a Collection.Request.Form?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some checkboxes with a unique id.  is it possible to find all the checkbox+uniquenum in a form collection?

something like -

```
foreach (var item in Collection.Request.Form["checkbox" + with UniqueIDNum])
{
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No.

Instead, you can loop through all of the keys, and check whether they start with `checkbox`.

For example:

```
foreach(string key in Request.Form) {
    if (!key.StartsWith("checkbox")) continue;
    ...
}
```

The [NameValueCollection enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.getenumerator.aspx) returns keys as strings.

Comment: Not by me... this was perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Or something like that

```
var checkBoxes = Request.Form.Keys.Where(rs=>rs.StartsWith("dummy"));
foreach(string key in checkBoxes){
 // Your code
}
```

Comment: `Request.Form.AllKeys`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with Linq (this should work, haven't tested):
I'm assuming also that the ID of the checkboxes is "checkbox[ID]". BTW, duplicate ID's in form fields is bad bad bad.

```
var checkboxes = (from key in Request.Form.AllKeys where key = "checkbox" + UniqueIDNum)
foreach(string key in checkboxes)
{
     //do stuff
}
```

Comment: That's needlessly slow.  `AllKeys` copies an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
        {   
            string a = fc["hdn_1"].ToString(); // if you know for sure that it will have a value.
            string lbl_1 = null;

            foreach (var key in fc.AllKeys)
            {
                if (key.Contains("txt_1"))
                {
                    lbl_1 = fc["txt_1"].ToString();
                }
            }
         }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in VB.NET, after having not worked with VB.NET in years and even then not having worked with it much, and I used Josh Wolf's answer to get the following:

```
Dim checkedOrders As IEnumerable(Of String) = From key In Request.Form.AllKeys Where key.StartsWith("chk")

If checkedOrders.Count > 0 Then
   ' do stuff, loop through checkedOrders, etc
End If
```

Note that my checkboxes all start with "chk" in the name (e.g. "chk1038", "chk1040", etc).