# Is there a way to access the values of a lot of form collection elements without manually typing the reference value associated with each element?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, formcollection

The above question is for ASP.NET MVC. I had to delete that part because of the title size restriction.

Let's say I have 100 checkboxes. Each checkbox has a reference value integer from 1 to 100. Some checkboxes are checked. Some are not. I press submit. A form collection is passed into an action method. Each checkbox of the form collection either has a value that represents if it is checked or not. Now I want to be able to access the values of each checkbox without manually typing the reference values from 1 to 100.

I've already tried just looping from 1- 100 over a FormCollection. In other words, I have the strings "1" to "100" created (not manually) to be put inside let's say a string a. Then I want form collection name[a] to be processed. Unfor. that does not happen.

Why this happens?

Can somebody give me a simple alternative?

Here is my code. Below, on the Form_Data[b], my debugger gives a null reference exception. If I put b="2(or any other integer from 3 to 91 inclusive)", my code works fine(which is why I suspect form collection reference values can only be read during compile-time).

```
for (int Speaker_Reference_Number = 2; Speaker_Reference_Number <= 91; Speaker_Reference_Number++)
{
    char a = '"';
    string c = a.ToString(); 
    string b ="";
    b = b + c;
    b = b + Speaker_Reference_Number;
    b = b + c;

    if (Form_Data[b].Equals("true,false"))
    {
        if (Speaker_Reference_Number <= 9)
        {
            Speakers = Speakers + "00" + Speaker_Reference_Number;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fix the formatting of your code please also do a google search here is something you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807713/can-i-loop-through-a-collection-request-form if not do a search on `foreach(Control in MVC `

Comment: How do I do that in stack overflow? When I click edit my code looks fine, but on stack overflow, my code looks horrible.

Comment: edit the changes now so you can see the difference.. also using `CTRL + K` will format your code properly when you highlight the code

Comment: It doesn't help me. If I only used my above checkboxes, that link would help me. However, I do have other form elements with reference names that are vastly different then the reference names I used for my above checkboxes.

Comment: thank you for advice on editing the code

Comment: Actually never mind, that type of foreach loop does not help me at all. My Form_Data[b] still does not get processed. I still get a null exception.

Comment: Can you access *any* controls inside Form_Data? Are you sure you're using the right keys?

Comment: Yes I can when I explicitly put the value of the string inside of the brackets.

Comment: For example, when I type in b="2" under b=b+c, everything is fine. However, I want my b to depend on a variable that changes value. I think that is causing me problems, but I am not sure, and I do not know any better alternatives. The last person showed me a link that was helpful, but it assumed you did not need to use the reference values later in your code. I need to do that. You can see how in my code I am sort of taking the reference values and using some of them after I access a corresponding formcollection string.

Comment: Yes, I am using the right keys.

Comment: Thanks Method Man! I figured out a solution with the help of your link!